# Idiomatic way of handling relationships in React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm wondering what the idiomatic way is in React/Redux for handling an API response that returns relationship data (and how to update the redux store). Say for example, when a user logs in, we make an API request like this to retrieve user data:

`GET /users/[:id]`

returns:

```
{
  "id": 14,
  "first_name": "Bob",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "appointments": [
    {
      "id": 234,
      "time": "morning"
    },
    {
      "id": 456,
      "time": "afternoon"
    }
  ],
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 789,
      "description": "EYE_DOCTOR"
    },
    {
      "id": 654,
      "description": "EAR_DOCTOR"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm confused between which of these 2 approaches is "better" (or if there is another one).

Approach 1: import relationship actions (rolesFetched, appointmentsFetched) into `userActions.js` and dispatch from there. Appropriate reducers will handle the actions they're interested in. Is this "good" practice to import roleActions into a userActions file?

```
// userActions.js

export function login(data) {
  return dispatch =>
    usersApi.fetch(data).then(user => {
      dispatch(userFetched(user));
      dispatch(rolesFetched(user.roles));
      dispatch(appointmentsFetched(user.appointments));
    });
}
```

Approach 2: Only dispatch the userFetched action and have the rolesReducer and appointmentsReducer listen for that (is it "good" practice to listen for user actions if you're a role reducer?):

```
// userActions.js

export function login(data) {
  return dispatch =>
    usersApi.fetch(data).then(user => {
      dispatch(userFetched(user));
    });
}

// rolesReducer.js

export default function rolesReducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_FETCHED:
            return action.user.roles;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

For this scenario, let's say that the roles are pretty much static. They only need to be refreshed upon login. But, the appointments data is refreshed much more often and has a separate action/reducer to fetch just appointments data (without having to fetch user/role data)

Comment: [There was a movement to ban asking for best practices.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312021/prevent-eliminate-best-practices-from-titles) Personally, I consider them asking for opinion.

Comment: Ok, I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your reducers and actions need to be based on workflows rather than based on entities.

In your case, instead of having userReducer, rolesReducer and appointmentReducer, you can have one loginReducer which handles all state updates related to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell how complex you app actually is but here are some comments:

- You don't need several reducers. Just have once reducer and one reducer function save the entire response from your API to your state. (If your state structure differs a bit, you can do the modifications inside that reducer).
- I think you just need to get your main state structure right and then start with one big reducer that handles all the different actions. If it becomes too big you can start slicing it up in different files but from an architectural standpoint, it will still be one reducer.
- If later you have a different API that just fetches the appointments for example, add a reducer function (not a new reducer) for that as well and update that user in the state.
- There is nothing wrong in my opinion in having a role reducer listen to user actions. But once again in your case they should be the same reducer since they access the same state.
- When designing your state, try to keep it as flat as possible (useful when accessing it from React later) and try to never duplicate data.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess my question is, what would you recommend the store look like? I use combineReducers to create a store that looks like `{ user: {}, roles: [], appointments: [] }`. I broke it up this way because I thought it would be more efficient in terms of components that subscribe to a "child" entity - i.e. instead of subscribing to `user` state, you can subscribe to `roles` state and only update/re-render components when the roles change rather than anything in user.

Could you expand on what could be "flattened" further?

Comment: I would leave it as it is because the roles and appointments are related to a user: `{ user: {roles: [], appointments: []}}`. It is fine when subscribing from a React component, as you can do something like:
`const mapStateToProps = (state) => {return {roles: state.user.roles};};` in which case your component will only update if the roles have changed.

Comment: Ok - but won't that make the reducer huge with a ton of actions to handle? Since basically all data in the application is related to the user, it kind of seems like we're jamming everything into one file. Whereas with this approach, you can get a bit more granular and organized. i.e. a userActions file, a userReducer, userApi. A rolesActions file, rolesReducer, and rolesApi, and same with appointments and any other data. How do you keep large files in your apps organized?

Comment: If you separate into several reducers, you will run into issues when one reducer needs to access data from another one or you need to write to several reducers at once. If your file becomes too big feel free to export each function in its own file: `export default function mainReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_FETCHED:
            return userFetched(state, action);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}` and your `userFetched()` function here is imported from a `./userFetched` file.

Comment: I am doing this for projects with hundreds of actions and its working great. I only use several reducers if the states for these reducers are completely isolated (no shared IDs or information). I guess what I am trying to say is feel free to split your code into as many files as possible but keep only one state object.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. But it's also kind of what I *think* I'm doing now - just separated out by files a bit more. Each function has it's own file, and everything is combined into one state object via redux's `combineReducers` method. But I think what you're trying to say it to make the data nested as opposed to top level elements (e.g. state being `{ user: { roles: [], appointments: []} }` vs `{ user: {}, roles: [], appointments: [] }` )

Comment: Yes keep the data nested to make it easy to understand your state and structure. But I am also saying that you should NOT use combineReducers in that case because reducers will not be aware of each others if you do that. Only use combineReducers if the data in your different reducers is completely unrelated